# Structure Declaration in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Whether following structure declaration is right.

```
typedef struct  { 
int roll; 
int  age ; 
} class[10];
```

When I do like this , compiler does not say any error.
But, when I assign `class[0].age=10,` 
am getting error. So here class[0] struct variable or structure name..

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are defining a *type* `class` which is an array of ten structs. To use this type you have to instatiate a variable of that type:

```
class x;
x[0].age = 10;
```

Maybe a slightly cleaner way would be to have two separate typedefs:

```
typedef struct { int roll; int  age; } foo_unit;
typedef foo_unit foo_array[10];

foo_array x;     /* now an array of 10 foo_units. */
foo_unit  y[10]; /* same thing */
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is

```
struct { 
  int roll; 
  int  age ; 
} class[10];
```

In your current code, class is defined as a type, because of the typedef. It's fine to define types this way, but you have to declare a variable afterwards:

```
typedef struct { 
  int roll; 
  int  age ; 
} class_type[10];

class_type class;
```

Answer (score 0):

By making this typedef, you define a type. So in order to get your desired effect you should do the following:

```
   class myclass;
   myclass[0].age = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`class` is the type name of an array of 10 elements each equal to the struct you define.

You should instantiate the type:

```
class classObject;
```

You have been possibly mislead by the basic syntax for declaring a struct:

```
struct class { 
   int roll; 
   int  age ; 
} class[10];
```

this declaration will also define a variable, array of 10 `struct class`.

By prefixing it with `typedef` you are changing the way the declaration works, and defining instead the type name instead of an instance of the struct.